# How to automatically log out from Google App Engine application after logging out of other Google serivices

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-userservice

I what my GAE app to be logout, when the user logout from an other google service.

I have SSO implemented in my domain.

have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029260/how-to-automatically-log-out-from-google-app-engine-application-after-logging-ou#comment-35408777) post.

Comment: If you use the users API, the authentication will be done agianst google credentials, if the user logged out of google services it will also logout from your app.

Comment: No... It doesn't logout..!!